# No se muestra el JPanel si no maximizo primero

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, jpanel

Estoy aprendiendo java, aunque tengo experiencia en C, en java soy muy novato.

tengo un problema que no se por que se produce, estoy creando un JPanel en el centro de un JFrame.

el JPanel solo tiene un cuadrado dibujado:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
   @Override
   public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
   {
      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
   }
```

}

La clase principal es la siguiente:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FirstFrame 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My First Windows");
        frame .setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(480, 270);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
    }

}
```

al ejecutarlo me aparece la ventana en blanco, me he pasado bastante tiempo buscando el fallo, pero para mi sorpresa si maximizo la ventana si que aparece el rectangulo en blanco, y ya puedo volver a su tamaño normal y el cuadrado sigue estando. ¿Por que ocurre esto?

aspecto inicial:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al maximizar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al volver al tamaño inicial:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola JUANJO, bienvenido, copié tu código, lo ejecute, y se comporta como se espera, estás dentro de un IDE?.

Comment: JUANJO el problema es uno bastante común cuando se empieza con Java Swing. Para solucionarlo, siempre debes agregar la linea `setVisible(true)` después de agregar los componentes al panel o ventana. En otras palabras, estas mostrando la ventana y luego agregas el panel, hazlo al revés, primero instancia la ventana con todos sus componentes y luego hazla visible. Esto te evitará el problema de que aveces se ve y aveces no. Por otro lado, la razón por la cual se muestra al redimensionar la ventana es por que se produce una actualización de los gráficos.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @MarcePuente: Estoy trabajando en eclipse, me he descargado la versión para desarrolladores java y ya esta.

Comment: @JFrame Has dado en el clavo!! He cambiado la linea de código de setVisible al final del método main y ya sale como esperaba. Muchas gracias.

Comment: PD: Estoy intentando votar el comentario como "aceptado" en las istrucciones de stackoverflow dice que marques la flecha hacia arriba a la izquierda del comentario, ("¿Cómo doy un voto positivo?
Haz click en la flecha hacia arriba en la parte izquierda de la publicación, o la flecha hacia arriba a la izquierda del comentario.")pero a mi no me sale esa flecha en los comentarios solo en mi pregunta.

Comment: @JUANJO Un comentario no es un respuesta formal, si no que es una forma de guiarte hacia la respuesta. Pero aun así he publicado una respuesta mas larga explicando la solución al problema. Puedes marcarla con el check OK si ha solucionado tu problema y la flecha arriba si te pareció útil.

Comment: JFrame, después de probar una buena cantidad de veces el ejemplo, estuve a nada de contradecirte.. pero me contuve, hoy te quiero agradecer, arrastraba el mismo problema, cuya solución fui postergando, no lo he probado, pero estoy seguro de que va a funcionar, gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hago una versión extendida de la respuesta en los comentarios. El problema es algo común cuando se empieza con Java Swing y ya ha sido tratado en varias preguntas en el sitio en ingles. Por mencionar algunas:

1. [Why are my items not showing up in JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409526/why-are-my-items-not-showing-up-in-jframe)
2. [Can not display the features using JFrame [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116071/can-not-display-the-features-using-jframe?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [JFrame with tabs is not being displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577924/jframe-with-tabs-is-not-being-displayed)

Estas preguntas tienen algo en común con tu código, y es que primero hacen visible la ventana y luego agregan los componentes. Al hacer esto surge un comportamiento extraño que hace que la ventana aveces muestre y aveces no muestre el contenido.

Para solucionar el problema solo debes agregar la linea `setVisble(true)` luego de haber agregado los componentes al panel o ventana. Esto hará que la ventana se muestre con todos los componentes que haz agregado al hacerla visible.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My First Windows");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(480, 270);

    MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

La razón por la cual se muestran los componentes al maximizar o redimensionar la ventana, es por que cuando esto sucede los componentes de la ventana se vuelven a pintar para mostrarse en pantalla.

Como observación adicional, este problema depende de varios factores y no solo de si se hace visible la ventana antes de agregar los componentes. Esto lo digo ya que aveces se muestra el contenido y aveces no, incluso en algunas distribuciones de Linux esto ni siquiera sucede, por lo que quizás el culpable del problema sea mas bien el como gestionan las ventanas los diferentes sistemas operativos, y para evitar se ha dicho que es recomendable hacer visible la ventana después de agregar los componentes.